# Froala 4.x -- editImageButtons works, but the dropdowns do not show

Tags: image, button, froala

Using Froala inside a bootstrap modal.

I've included plugins, and can insert an image (and successfully upload), but the dropdown buttons in the edit image buttons do not show.  So when clicking the image, the image buttons show like normal, but clicking on a dropdown button (like align image), the options do NOT show.

I've set the z-index in froala instance to 2501 already (and that made the buttons show, just not the dropdowns).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I added these two lines to .fr-dropdown-wrapper in froala_editor.pkgd.css:

height: auto;
max-height: 275px;

I found that it worked when i included old Froala2 css and dug down to see what css it was picking up from that file.  Adding those 2 lines to the updated versions seems to fix the problem.

No idea why, but if anyone else has this issue, try this.